# Loading dplyr via Rprofile.site in Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio, dplyr

Since I've found it, I use dplyr religiously. Since I use it so much, I tried putting `library(dplyr)`  in my .First() function in Rprofile.

That loads dplyr, but when I fire up Rstudio, some of dplyr's functions get masked. For example, when I try to do:

```
foo <- mtcars %>% filter( cyl == 4 )
```

I get the follow error:

```
Error in filter(mtcars, cyl == 4) : object 'cyl' not found
```

A bit of troubleshooting revealed that if I run library(dplyr) again in the console, the problem clears right up--clearly one/some of dplyr's functions are getting masked by something further down the search path (or up, depending on how you look at it.

When I look at my search() path, I see that there are a host of other packages being loaded after dplyr, which isn't really what I want (I'd prefer that dplyr was the last thing loaded, or at least nearly last):

```
[1] ".GlobalEnv"        "tools:rstudio"     "package:stats"     "package:graphics"  "package:grDevices" "package:utils"    
[7] "package:datasets"  "package:xlsx"      "package:xlsxjars"  "package:rJava"     "package:dplyr"     "package:methods"  
[13] "Autoloads"         "package:base"
```

I'm on Windows 7, using RStudio v.0.98.1028. Because I'm really unclear how Windows + RStudio handles the home directory, I'm editing Rprofile in `C:/Program Files/R/R-3.1.1/etc/`. Any suggestions?

Comment: What happens if you don't put it inside the `.First` function? That is, if you just put it naked into the `.Rprofile.site` file?

Comment: Unfort. I get the same error and the search() order is still the same.

Comment: FWIW I think putting packages in your .Rprofile is a bad idea because it much it harder to reproduce your code.

Comment: Long term follow-up on this, I've followed the advice of @hadley and moved creating an Rstudio snippet that writes a couple lines of code to load all the libraries I find myself using regularly. Nowadays, I type `prep` and whack Tab a couple times, then hit ctrl + shift + s and all my libraries are loaded, plus, when I return the script later, everything loads properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the startup order for R (see `?Startup`), `.First()` is called before `.First.sys()` which loads the other packages. It is the `stats` package that overwrites `filter`.

`.First.sys()` uses `options("defaultPackages")` to determine what to load, so I suggest you edit that in your `.First()` function with:

```
options(defaultPackages=c(getOption("defaultPackages"),"dplyr"))
```

Comment: Ah, that did it! The one thing I had to change is that options('defaultPackages') is a list--what you had above added dplyr as a new list item.

To get dplyr into the vector itself, I had to use:
    options(defaultPackages=c(options("defaultPackages")[[1]],"dplyr"))

Thanks!